# How do you add multiple pages throughout an InDesign file?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I have an InDesign document with 50 pages.

I would like to add a new page after each existing page for a new total of 100 pages.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: A quickish (but manual) way would be to alternate between the shortcuts for _Go to next page_ (Alt + PgDn on a Mac) and _Insert page_ (Cmd + Shift + P) on a Mac. Wouldn't take more than a minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

Without having to do scripting, you can use a macro program like QuicKeys.

Make a shortcut for the Insert Page function. In Keyboard Shortcuts it's under the Pages Panel. Use the shortcut for making the macro.

Setup an macro to **Insert Page**, then **Enter** (for the OK button), then goto **Next Page** (already a shortcut for that).

Starting from page 1, run the macro to repeat 50 times.

You will probably have to add in some delay between actions to get the timing right.